# Removing Pokemon from dictionary

Tags: c#

I have this code here and when I input 1, user able to input Pokemon.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    namespace PokemonPocket
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
                PokemonMenu(pokemonMasters, pokemonSkills);
            }
            static void PokemonMenu(List<PokemonMaster> pokemans, List<PokemonSkill> pokeskills)
            {
                // From now on myDictionary is available for any menu option 
                var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
                while (true)
                { // <- loop until exit option (key 'Q') is pressed
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
                    Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
                    Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
                    Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");
    
                    char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    
                    if (menu == '1')
                    { //Part 1 - Adding the Pokemon
                        
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon Name :");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon HP : ");
                        int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon EXP : ");
                        int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (name != "Charmander" && name != "Eevee" && name != "Pikachu")
                        // Check that only these 3 can be added
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Only can add Charmander, Eevee and Pikachu!");
                        }
                        else{ //if Pokemon name is correct ->
                            if (myDictionary.Count <= 0)
                            {
                            
                                myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Name", name);
                                myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's HP", hp.ToString());
                                myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's EXP", exp.ToString());
                                Console.WriteLine("Pokemon has been added!");
    
                            }
                    }
                }
                    else if (menu == '2'){} //need help here
```

When I input 2, I want the Pokemon that the user has input to be deleted. I understand in Python I can use pop() to remove the item in a dictionary, but I am not sure how to do it in C#

Comment: By the way, if you type `myDictionary.`, Visual Studio will prompt you with the methods that can be used with that instance. Typing/Selecting A method name followed by `(` will show the parameters it takes. If there are multiple overloads you can use the up/down arrow keys to see the different signatures.. The methods are also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0#methods). I would suggest trying `Remove`.

Comment: Have you read [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0#methods) for Dictionary?

Comment: Is it this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could better make a class `Pokemon` that holds `name`, `hp` and `exp` and then add it to a dictionary. If you add all of these parameters seperately, you will end up with three different records. If I look at your code I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

To delete a pokemon, you could just call the `Remove` method of the dictionary.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in what you are saying.  But in order to be a good answer you should put this into code for the OP, who is obviously inexperienced and needs help.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith agreed, it's just that I don't really have the time right now. If you want you can edit my answer to add the code.

Comment: when you don't have time for a good answer, it's better to write a comment.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann don't have 50 reputation yet

Comment: @AntonThomas and you won't get it without taking the time to write good answers ;)